# JavaScript/VBA Automation: Changing the onclick attribute

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, vba, automation, browser-automation

I am trying to change the function call from the `onclick` event of a button on a form using automation in VBA. Function `X` is already hard-coded into the webpage, and I do not have access to change that code. (The page is internal to my company, but I am not in that department).

When my scenario fits, I want to replace function `X` with a new function `Y`.

I've seem similar questions to this one SO, but it appears most refer to changing an element attribute from within JS code. My problem is that I need to so this in VBA and I'm not sure how to get there.

[This site](http://reference.sitepoint.com/javascript/Element/getAttribute) has a good deal of information regarding this process (`setAttribute`, `getAttribute`, etc.), including useful info re: caveats when working with one browser vs. another. *All my code will be interfacing with IE (what the company provides), so no need to worry about the other browser options.*

When trying to change the `onclick` attribute, the VBE watch panel shows a change in the attribute, but it does not behave as expected. After I have changed the attribute, nothing at all happens when I click (either through my automation of `objButton.Click` / `objButton.onclick`, or actually manually clicking the button). I have also tried this on other attributes (i.e. `onfocus`) with the same results. The link above mentions IE has some difficulty with this, but I'm not overly familiar with JavaScript and I am having trouble following the guide.

What I have tried is the following, all of which have the same result.

Option 1:

```
Set TEST = myIEWindow.Document.createattribute("onclick")
TEST.nodevalue = "function anonymous() {alert(""test""); };"
objButton.setAttributeNode TEST
```

Option 2:

```
objButton.Attributes("onclick").value = "function anonymous() {alert(""test""); };"
```

Option 3:

```
objButton.Attributes("onclick").value = "alert(""test"");"
```

Option 4:

```
objButton.setAttribute "onclick", "alert(""test"");"
```

Option 5:

```
objButton.onclick = "function() { alert(""test""); };"
```

While trying these different methods out, I did notice that the `onclick` attribute **type** in the VBE watch window changes from its original type of Variant/Object to Variant/String after attempting to coerce the button to call the new function, and I feel this has something to do with my problem.

Can someone please explain how (if possible) I can get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change this on the element property directly.

```
var objButton = document.getElementById("buttonId");
objButton.onclick = function() { alert("test"); };
```

Comment: That looks more like JS, not VBA, and I am not able to change the JS directly. I tried `objButton.onclick = "function() { alert(""test""); };"` based on your answer, but this doesn't work either, unfortunately. It has the same effect as the other methods I've listed. I can see in the watch panel that the attribute value has changed (again, also the type from Variant/Object to Variant/String) and nothing happens when I click.

Comment: Call myIEWindow.Document.execScript("document.getElementById('buttonId').onclick = function() {alert('test');};")

Comment: This gives me an "Object doesn't support this property or method" error. Looking now for more info RE: `execScript`...

Comment: Playing with the example, I did get this to work: `myIEWindow.Document.ParentWindow.execScript "alert('test');"` Will try adapting it to my real function code!

Comment: This worked, minus an apparent error in my JS (returned 80020101) but that's a different issue now. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!